# To insert a value in a String

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to manipulate a string to get the required value.

I need to change `ACTUALSTRING99` to `ACTUALSTRING_99`. Currently I am passing this `ACTUALSTRING99` to a function and returning it as `ACTUALSTRING_99` in the following way.

```
SELECT 'VALUE'                                                                                               AS ACTUAL,
  REGEXP_REPLACE('VALUE', '[[:digit:]]')                                                                     AS STRING,
  REGEXP_REPLACE('VALUE', '[[:alpha:]]')                                                                     AS DIGIT,
  concat(concat(REGEXP_REPLACE('VALUE', '[[:digit:]]'),'_'),REGEXP_REPLACE('VALUE', '[[:alpha:]]')) AS REQUIRED
FROM dual;
```

Passing VALUE as`ACTUALSTRING99`. Do we have any other simple way (using or without using regular expression) to do it with out calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prepend underscore before numerical part of the string, you can simply use regexp_replace with backreference.

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE('actualstring99','([[:digit:]]+)','_\1')
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using substring and length functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('VALUE',0,LENGTH('VALUE')-2) || '_' || 
   SUBSTR('VALUE',LENGTH('VALUE')-2,LENGTH('VALUE')) 
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: But I cant confirm the position. I have to put an '_' in between number and string.